# Showing that $C[0,1]$ is not complete

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, banach-spaces, cauchy-sequences

Let $C[0,1]$ have the following norm for finite $p$:
$$||f||_p=\left(\int_0^1|f(x)|^pdx\right)^{1/p}$$
I want to show that $C[0,1]$ is not complete for this norm.

> How do I do this?

What I know:
So I want to find a Cauchy sequence that does not converge in $C[0,1]$.
My idea was
$$f_n(x) := \begin{cases}
 0   & \text{if $0 \le x < \frac1{2}-\frac{1}{n}$}\\
 \frac{n}{2}(x-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n}) & \text{if $\frac {1}{2}-\frac{1}{n} \le x \le \frac {1}{2} + \frac {1}{n}$}\\
 1              & \text{if $ \frac {1}{2} + \frac {1}{n} <x \leq 1 $}
\end{cases}$$
It is clear that this converges to
$$f(x) := \begin{cases}
 0   & \text{if $0 \le x < \frac1{2}$}\\
 1              & \text{if $ \frac {1}{2} <x \leq 1 $}
\end{cases}$$
which is not continuous. The point is now to prove that $f_n$ is Cauchy, but I have no idea how to prove this. Can you help?

Edit:
According to me, $||f_n-f_m||_p=\left(\int_{\frac1{2}-\frac{1}{m}}^{\frac1{2}+\frac{1}{m}}|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|^pdx\right)^{1/p}$. BUt how do I continue from here?

Comment: Have you considered explicitly computing $\|f_n - f_m\|$?

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan Please see edit, is that correct?

Comment: It's sufficient to find an upper bound for $\lVert f_n - f_m\rVert$ that converges to $0$ when $m,n \to \infty$. Use a bound for $\lvert f_n(x) - f_m(x)\rvert$ on $\bigl[\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{m}, \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{m}\bigr]$ if $n \geqslant m$.

Comment: @DanielFischer What for bound can I use?

Comment: Since $0 \leqslant f_k(x) \leqslant 1$, you can bound the difference by $1$. Looking a bit closer, you can find a smaller bound, but that doesn't matter.

Comment: @DanielFischer But why does $||f_n-f_m||$ converge to $0$ if $|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|$ is bounded?

Comment: It's not _that_ simple. But look at your expression for $\lVert f_n - f_m\rVert_p$, and estimate that by replacing the integrand $\lvert f_n(x) - f_m(x)\rvert^p$ by a constant upper bound.

Comment: @DanielFischer Would I then get an upper bound of $\left(\frac{2}{m}\right)^{1/p}$?

Comment: Yes (assuming $n \geqslant m$). And that gives you Cauchy.

Comment: @DanielFischer I am going to write an answer for this, would you mind to check it when it's finished?

Comment: @DanielFischer Please see my answer, it still seems a little too simple for my taste...

Comment: You also should explicitly say that $f_n(x) = f_m(x)$ for $\bigl\lvert x-\frac{1}{2}\bigr\rvert \geqslant \frac{1}{m}$. But showing that the sequence is Cauchy is easy. What is harder is giving a correct proof that the sequence doesn't converge in $C([0,1])$ if you don't have any Lebesgue theory you can use. It's surprisingly hard to not omit any steps in that.

Comment: @DanielFischer I thought that was the easy part, what can go wrong in that proof?

Comment: Leaving out details. Most students leave out details. It's so obvious that one is very tempted to short-cut it.

Comment: @DanielFischer Have I left out any details?

Comment: Yes. _Why_ does it follow that $f(x) = 0$ for $x < 1/2$ and $f(x) = 1$ for $x > 1/2$? It's not hard to give a correct argument for that, but one has to see that it's necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Let $n,m\in\mathbb{N}$ and $n\geq m$.
Then $|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|\le 1$ on $[\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{m},\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{m}]$, since $0\le |f_i(x)|\le 1$ for all $i$.
This means that $$||f_n-f_m||_p=\left(\int_{\frac1{2}-\frac{1}{m}}^{\frac1{2}+\frac{1}{m}}|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|^pdx\right)^{1/p}\le \left(\int_{\frac1{2}-\frac{1}{m}}^{\frac1{2}+\frac{1}{m}}1dx\right)^{1/p}=\left(\frac{2}{m}\right)^{1/p}.$$
For $n,m\rightarrow\infty$, we see that $||f_n-f_m||_p\rightarrow 0$. Thus $(f_n)$ is Cauchy.

Suppose $f_n$ has a limit $f$ in $C[0,1]$. Then $\int_{0}^{1}|f(x)-f_n(x)|^pdx\leq||f-f_n||_p\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$. This gives us that 
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
 0   & \text{if $0 \le x < \frac1{2}$}\\
 1              & \text{if $ \frac {1}{2} \le x \leq 1 $}
\end{cases}$$
which is not continuous.